# Move integer to the nearest divisible by 4 in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'd like to move an integer up to the nearest 'divisible by 4' number in C++, but not if the number is currently divisible by 4.  Here's my best attempt, but I'm sure this is suboptimal:

```
offset = (offset & 3) ? (offset | 3) +1 : offset;
```

There must surely be a fast way of doing this that doesn't include the tertiary IF statement?

Additional note:  In this case offset is a 32-bit int.

Comment: how about `(offset + 3) & ~(decltype(offset))3`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
offset = (offset + 3) & ~(decltype(offset))3;
```

---

Or

```
#include <type_traits>
// ...
offset = (offset + 3) &
    ~static_cast<std::remove_reference<decltype(offset)>::type>(3);
```

if you need to support the possibility that `offset` is a reference type, such as `size_t&`. Thanks @BaummitAugen.

It also seems to work when `offset` is wider than `int` even without the type cast, `offset = (offset + 3) & ~3;`, but I am uncertain as to whether or not it is mandated by the language standard.

---

This algorithm can be described in English as "add 3 then round down".

The rounding down part is done by setting the two least significant bits to zero by binary arithmetics. Unsetting of bits is done by applying binary AND with the inverse bit pattern, in other words we make a bit pattern of all the bits whose value we want to keep unchanged and apply it as a mask.

Binary representation of `3`: `00000011`

We get the inverse bit mask with the `~` (bitwise NOT, not to be confused with `!` logical NOT) operator: `~3`

For the `~` operator, the size of the operand determines the size of the result, so on my machine `~(unsigned char)3 == 252` (`1111 1100`) and `~(unsigned int)3 == 4294967292` (`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100`). The default size for an integer literal is `int`.

When `offset` is a wider type (has more bits) than `int`, we need the operand to `~` to be widened so the bitmask matches. This is why we cast the literal `3` to the same type as `offset`.

Comment: Why should we use casting?

Comment: This will fail when offset is a 64-bit type and larger than INT_MAX.

Comment: essentially this is "add 3 then round down"

Comment: Add 3 then round down - why didn't I think of that.

Comment: And yes it will fail if offset+3 overflows it but then there is no such number that solves the problem.

Comment: @ikh The cast is necessary when `offset` is of a type that is wider than `int`. Working on an illustrative example.

Comment: I presume decltype(offset) is resolved at compile time?

Comment: @MattParkins Yes, it is. It resolves to "the type of `offset`", so if `offset` is a `size_t`, the entire line resolves to `offset = (offset + 3) & ~(size_t)3;`

Comment: @MagnusHoff Oh, then, should `(offset + 3)` be `(offset + (decltype(offset))3)` too?

Comment: No, because he only needs to know the width of the int to set all the bits to 1 in it.  Not necessary elsewhere.  Anyway, I've picked this as the right answer for having the fewest ops and its portability.

Comment: decltype(offset) is there to ensure that the mask works properly. If offset is 64 bits you'd have a problem with ~3 which is 1 for every bit except the 1 and 2 bit, but as 3 is a 32-bit int, the higher bits would be zeros not 1s like they should be.

Comment: During testing I discovered that it worked like a charm without the typecast. This is the case because `~3` is negative in two's complement representation, and this negative number is then sign-extended to fit `offset`. Can we rely on this behavior according to the standard? In other words, is the cast actually not necessary?

Comment: This does not compile if `offset` is a reference. [Live.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04f3d56722e6bf3b) Adding `std::remove_reference` seems to solve that. [Live.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08ba478b94806f1d)

Answer (score 4):

```
offset = ((offset +3 ) >>  2) << 2;
```

However I prefer Magnus Hoff's solution.

offset should ideally be an unsigned type. If you make this an inline function you can use a parameter that is unsigned. You can also parameterise the power, of course, i.e. 2 in this case. In such a case the number you add would be (1<

So for a general solution:

```
template< typename U >
U roundUpPower2( U num, size_t nBits )
{
   return (( num + (static_cast<U>(1) << nBits) - 1 ) >> nBits) << nBits;
}
```

Using a bitmask rather than two shits

```
template< typename U >
U roundUpPower2( U num, size_t nBits )
{
   U mask = (static_cast<U>(1) << nBits) - 1;
   return (num + mask) & ~mask;
}
```

Note the purpose of casting the 1 is that if you are using 64 bit arithmetic your nBits might be any value from 1 to 63 and plain `1` is of type int, signed and probably 32 bits, in which case the arithmetic would go wrong if nBits is 32 or higher if you don't cast it.

Comment: This looks ideal for me.

Comment: Since you said it looked ideal I added a more generic solution.

Comment: Great generic solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
number = 4 * ((number + 3) / 4)
```

Whether it's more efficient depends on your setup - profile and see.

Comment: The compiler would optimize this to some shifts/masks

Comment: @MattMcNabb ... assuming that's more efficient on the target HW. And that is precisely why I prefer to leave such optimisations to the compiler - it knows the HW better. If I want a multiple of 4, I will use multiplication and division to express it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
offset += -offset & 3;
```

Depending on the division rest (0, 1, 2, or 3), it adds the appropriate amount to round up (0, 3, 2 or 1).